# Multiple Facebook-like button on a page

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am making a website which is having more than 10 products on a single page. The problem is that how i can add a Facebook like button for each product and how will i manage them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the ref label - fb_ref and fb_source. there are lots of questions here on how to handle multiple likes. Please search before posting a Q - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiple+likes

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this for a while so I made a tool to help with it. It will store all of the open graph information and generate the like button code for you. Try it and let me know if it works for you.

[Facebook/Open Graph Like Button Generator](http://o-e.us/fb/lbg)